# Which Docutment AI models can be used for a document containing check box items?

Tags: neural-networks

Need to do Q & A on documents containing a check box list like below.
Question: which toppings are selected by a customer?
Answer: Strawberry, M & Ms.

```
Select optional toppings:

[X] Strawberry 
[ ] Chocolate
[X] M & Ms
[ ] Almonds
[ ] Hot Fudge
```

Would like to know which kind Doc AI models can be used for this case?